# how to change horizontal row to vertical column data display in html table

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller

I'm getting the JSON value and populating in the table, but I need to change the horizontal style to vertical when displaying the table.  I'm m using an MVC controller and updating the model, and assigning the model data to table.unble to get serial number in my first column.

I want to show the table like this:

```
    name   deviceid    time      location   status
    1      123         10.50     kolkata    23
    2      2332        11.11     hyderabad  44
    3      333         04.54     chennai    11

    but im getting the table format like this

   name  deviceid      time      location   status
    1      123         10.50     kolkata    23
    1      2332        11.11     hyderabad  44
    1      333         04.54     chennai    11



      <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr class="success">
            <th>Bin id</th>
            <th>device id</th>
            <th>filled in %</th>
            <th>Updated time</th>
            <th>Area</th>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr> <td class="success">1</td>
                <td class="success">@item.deviceid</td>
                <td class="danger">@item.Filled.ToString("N2") %</td>
                <td class="info">@item.UpdatedTime</td>
                <td class="warning">@item.Area</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop the columns in a single row `<tr>` only

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr class="success">
        <th class="success">Bin Id</th>
        <th>device id</th>
        <th>filled in %</th>
        <th>Updated time</th>
        <th>Area</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    // here you need the index values for the name column so i am giving i value to first column

    @foreach (var item in Model.Select((value,i) => new {i, value}))
    {
      <tr class="warning">
        <td class="success">@item.i</td>
        <td>@item.value.deviceid</td>
        <td>@item.value.Filled.ToString("N2") %</td>
        <td>@item.value.UpdatedTime</td>
        <td>@item.value.Area</td>
      </tr>
    }     
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Add +1 to @{item.i+1} <td class="success">@{item.i+1}</td>

Comment: Use the flower braces @{item.i+1} or @{item.i++}

Answer (score 3):

```
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr class="success">
                    <th>Bin id</th>
                    <th>device id</th>
                    <th>filled in %</th>
                    <th>Updated time</th>
                    <th>Area</th>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="success">@item.deviceid</td>

                        <td class="danger">@item.Filled.ToString("N2") %</td>    
                        <td class="info">@item.UpdatedTime</td>
                        <td class="warning">@item.Area</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
             </tbody>
        </table>
```

The `<th>` tag defines a header cell in an HTML table.

An HTML table has two kinds of cells:

- Header cells - contains header information (created with the `<th>` element)
- Standard cells - contains data (created with the `<td>` element)

  The text in `<th>` elements are bold and centered by default.
- The text in `<td>` elements are regular and left-aligned by default.

You'll get the table view as expected. I couldn't figure out why you've added the css. so add your column css accordingly!
Hope this helps!

Comment: cool! Please add tweaks for your column name. The answer is for the functionality alone. :)

Comment: i didnt get what do u mean by tweek in the column

Comment: I've followed the same names as you've given in code. Not in the expected output. Am I clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136592/discussion-between-swapna-and-keerthana-prabhakaran).

Comment: This answer is better imo. Should've been the accepted answer